# Creating a Scriptable Object in the Unity Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So apparently i suck at listening at my university, because i can't figure this out, not even with google...
How do you create a scriptable object in the editor? I have the project open, it looks like this:

[image]

Click the Create button as if you wanted to create a folder or C# script or anything.

[image]

Select the ScriptableObject from the popup menu.

[image]

Get this panel and finalize the object after selecting the script for it.

The problem is: i don't have the ScriptableObject button. I have a script that is a scriptable object (to make sure i even copied the one from the project of the university). I restarted Unity, i checked if there were any packages installed (there werent) and i googled quite a bit. But i just can't seem to get this working...

Is there anything i have to install or add first?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check this tutorial ? https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects

Comment: ...I was watching it in the background (as its an hour long) and right as i posted this the explanation came. It works different than the uni project but its works ( using [CreateAssetMenu()] above the class). the funny thing is, the uni project doesnt do tha and it works for them...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need another script to add the button which will create an instance from that scriptable object. something like that

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

public class MakeScriptableObject {
    [MenuItem("Assets/Create/My Scriptable Object")]
    public static void CreateMyAsset()
    {
        MyScriptableObjectClass asset = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<MyScriptableObjectClass>();

        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(asset, "Assets/NewScripableObject.asset");
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();

        EditorUtility.FocusProjectWindow();

        Selection.activeObject = asset;
    }
}
```

You can check this [Introduction to Scriptable Objects tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects) on unity website.

Comment: this can be made quicker with adding [CreateAssetMenu()] above the class (which atomates the above code). Thanks so much! this was driving me crazy... the funny thing is, the university project i have open neither has the CreateAssetMenu nor does it have the code above... i'm just glad it's working now tho!

Comment: @Yiasmat That's not quite the same thing [CreateAssetMenu()] gives you no opportunity to run your own code during the creation, like assigning a unique id to the SO for example.

Answer (score 6):

I can't comment so just place it like answer:
Don't forget to use **UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.GenerateUniqueAssetPath** coz simple **AssetDatabase.CreateAsset** can erase your data:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

public class MakeScriptableObject
{
    [MenuItem("Assets/Create/My Scriptable Object")]
    public static void CreateMyAsset()
    {
        MyScriptableObjectClass asset = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<MyScriptableObjectClass>();

        string name = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.GenerateUniqueAssetPath("Assets/NewScripableObject.asset");
        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(asset, name);
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();

        EditorUtility.FocusProjectWindow();

        Selection.activeObject = asset;
    }
}
```